# Perl : Extract an HTML element with a particular class using HTML::TokeParser

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the HTML content present in < td > tags corresponding to the class "tablehead1".

```
< td class="tablehead1"> Market < /td >
```

While parsing, i'm getting all the text contents of < td > tags present in the whole html file. 
But I need only the content in < td > tags with the particular class "tablehead1" .

Where am i going wrong in the below code ?

```
use HTML::TokeParser;

open(DATA,"<KeyStats.html") or die "Can't open data";
my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new(*DATA);

while (my $token = $p->get_tag('td')) {

 my $url = $token->[1]{class} || "tablehead1";
 my $text = $p->get_trimmed_text("/td");

 if (length($text)<30&&length($text)>0) {  print "$text\n"; }
}
```

Comment: Use [HTML::TableExtract](http://www.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html).

Comment: Also `length($text)<30&&length($text)>0` is an abomination. There is no shortage of space characters I know of. Plus `$text and (length($text) < 30)` is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really perform the check whether the `class` is really `tablehead1`.

Replace

```
my $url = $token->[1]{class} || "tablehead1";
```

by

```
next unless $token->[1]{class} eq "tablehead1";
```

should give you the expected results. Also, you should add a check whether the actual `<td>` really has a key `class`, e.g. by

```
next unless grep( /^class$/, @{$token->[2]} ) && $token->[1]{class} eq "tablehead1";
```